# Merge two graph into one (Adding edges) R igraph

Tags: r, igraph

I'm new to R and the question may be easy. But I failed to find answer by myself.

I have two edgelists share common nodes. I want to put them into one graph. But I hope if node1 and node2 have edges in both EL1 and EL2, there are two lines between them. And these two lines should be different color, indicating they are from different edgelists.

I've tried `graph.union()`, however it seems that even I have Node1 -> Node2 twice in the `graph`, it only display once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have the edgelists,  you can just `rbind` them to make a big edgelist for the combined graph. You can assign a color to the edges based on which list they came from. Since you do not provide any data, I illustrate with a simple example.

```
library(igraph)

## Example data
EL1 = matrix(c("A", "B", "B", "C", "C", "D", "D", "A"), ncol=2, byrow=T)
g1 = graph_from_edgelist(EL1)
EL2 = matrix(c("A", "B", "B", "E", "E", "A"), ncol=2, byrow=T)
g2 = graph_from_edgelist(EL2)

## Combine the graphs
BigEL = rbind(EL1, EL2)
BigG = graph_from_edgelist(BigEL)
Col = c("red", "blue")[c(rep(1, nrow(EL1)), rep(2, nrow(EL2)))]
plot(BigG, edge.color=Col)
```

[image: Combined Graph]